ERROR: Package 'imageio' requires a different Python: 2.7.17 not in '>=3.5'
I am doing Medical Image Analysis, in that I need package imageio in jupyter notebook. I am writing this command
!pip install imageio

Giving me error like this
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting imageio
  Using cached imageio-2.9.0.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
ERROR: Package 'imageio' requires a different Python: 2.7.17 not in '>=3.5'

My kernel Jupyter one set to Python3
!python3 --version 
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc. 

I tried
!pip3 install imageio


which correctly Installed it with this output
Requirement already satisfied: imageio in /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from imageio) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=8.3.2 in /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from imageio) (8.4.0)

But still when import imageio package
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import nibabel as nib
import cv2
import imageio
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from ipywidgets import *
from PIL import Image
from fastai.basics import *
from fastai.vision.all import *
from fastai.data.transforms import *

Giving me ImportError
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-9c1456a18eb5> in <module>()
      6 import nibabel as nib
      7 import cv2
----> 8 import imageio
      9 from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
     10 from ipywidgets import *

ImportError: No module named imageio


So, How can I install it?
I tried pip3 and I was expecting to remove imageio ``importError

This would suggest that pip3 is not installing to the same environment as your code is actually running in. What is the output when you import sys and print(sys.executable)?

@nog642 /usr/bin/python

That is the problem. Your jupyter notebook is running in your system python, rather than your conda environment. How are you starting jupyter notebook? You should be starting it from inside the fastai2 environment.

Actually I am using Tunnel mode bcoz of University GPU.
Conda activate fastai2
(fastai2) jayakumars@nvidia2020:~$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8878

It seems like jupyter notebook is installed globally on the system and not in the environment. Try running pip install notebook from inside the fastai2 env, then restarting the notebook server.

@nog642 it says requirement already satisfied

What is the output of which jupyter inside the environment? You can try running /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8878 with the explicit path instead of just jupyter.

@nog642 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nibabel'. Earlier It was working now it is not....

Are you saying just jupyter also no longer works? And /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/bin/pip install notebook says requirement already satisfied for notebook and doesn't install anything? If that's the case, you may want to just create a new conda environment from scratch (and use Python 3.10 while you're at it maybe). You could try pip install nibabel in the environment before that though, as a last ditch effort, though it doesn't make sense that jupyter wouldn't automatically install dependencies.

Ok I will try 3.10 when making a new environment & then run all cells.

Actually, I think I misunderstood. You meant that you get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nibabel' when actually running your code, right? Not just when running the notebook server. This is because you import nibabel in your code but it is not installed to the environment. This makes sense. You can !pip install all the packages you need for your project from jupyter notebook now.

Earlier It was not giving because I had already installed it. But when you say to run notebook with full path  /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/bin/pip install notebook then it starts giving install error

You had installed it to the global environment, not the fastai2 environment. It was working because Jupyter Notebook was running in the global environment too, which is not what you want. You will need to install all the packages you need into the conda environment.

I thought Whenever We change Env we also change jupyter notebook automatically too.... So , I was wrong thingking?

You had Jupyter Notebook installed globally, and not installed in the env. So when you ran jupyter, even though the env was activated, it was still running Jupyter Notebook on the global python. You had to pip install notebook inside the env to install Jupyter Notebook inside the env to have your notebook actually run inside the env.

Ya . I was running Jupyter notebook in env only because I had already ran pip install notebook

You are getting this error because Jupyter Notebook is installed for your system Python (/usr/bin/python), not for your conda environment (/home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/bin/python). Therefore when you started Jupyter Notebook with jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8878, even though you had run conda activate fastai2, it was still running the Jupyter Notebook installed for the global Python, and therefore your code was also running in the global python. You can check this by running import sys and print(sys.executable).
To run your code inside the fastai2 environment, the easiest way at least is to install Jupyter Notebook inside the environment and run that. So run conda activate fastai2 and then inside the environment run pip install notebook (or to be safe, /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/bin/pip install notebook).
Then you should be able to run jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8878 inside the env (or to be safe, /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8878). You can verify that your code is running in the environment with import sys and print(sys.executable) again.
Finally, you may need to install the packages you were using (numpy, pandas, matplotlib, nibabel, etc.) in the fastai2 environment, since they may not be installed yet. You can do this with pip install in the environment (or to be safe, /home/jayakumars/anaconda3/envs/fastai2/bin/pip install). You can also run these commands using ! from inside jupyter notebook.

Please suggest using the magic command in conjunction with install commands run in the notebook and not the exclamation point. The magic install commands were added in 2019 to avoid the issues that using the exclamation point with install commands can cause. The magic install commands insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running while the exclamation point does not! Please see my recent comments here, and links therein, for more about this.
